# Intellitrace production not creating itrace file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, intellitrace

Everything so far went great with Intellitrace, however now when setting up production collecting, it's just not doing it. No error, everything is...just doesn't create the .itrace file.

So what I did, I have WIN 7, 32bit with SP1. I have on it IIS7.

I wanted to replicate the FabrikamFiber demo from the Hands on labs. And it worked for F5 debugging, however this other thing simply doesn't.

One thing to note is that I'm testing this on a virtual VMWare machine, both collecting and debugging.

I use the normal commands, and I've even put Everyone for test as a user to both Intellitrace folder and logs folder.

PS C:\Users\IEUser> Start-IntelliTraceCollection "FabrikamFiber.Extranet.Web" C:\IntelliTrace\collection_plan.ASP.NET.trace.xml C:\IntelliTrace

All paths are good!

But simply, when running the application it doesn't record anything.

Executing status command, give back this:

ApplicationPool    : FabrikamFiber.Extranet.Web
ProcessId          : 4068
ProcessStartTime   : 10/8/2012 11:48:20 PM
CollectionPlanPath : C:\Windows\Temp\FabrikamFiber.Extranet.Web_collection_plan
                     .ASP.NET.trace.xml
OutputPath         :

Where Outputpath is empty!

And no .itrace file is created?!

Anyone have any idea?

Vladan

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if the [IntelliTrace .cab file wasn't expanded like this after downloading it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_Install_the_IntelliTrace_Stand_Alone_Collector):

**expand /f:* IntelliTraceCollection.cab .**